# Affect different element in parent div on hover

Tags: jquery

When I hover over an `<h3>` within a `<div>`, it expands all `<ul>` elements in all `<div>` elements with this class.

I'm a bit confused on how to affect *only* the `<ul>` within the `<div>` where I am hovering over the `<h3>`?

I have HTML structured like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.sidemenugroup h3").hover(function() {
    jQuery("div.sidemenugroup ul").slideDown()
  }, function() {
    jQuery("div.sidemenugroup ul").slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
div.sidemenugroup ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</div>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some other text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li2nd>List Item 1</li>
      <li>2nd List Item 2</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identify the element from which the "hover" event was fired by using JavaScript's ["this" keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

> "When a function is used as an event handler, its `this` is set to the element the event fired from"

Once you have identified the element that fired "hover" (`<h3>`), you can traverse from that element to its corresponding `<ul>`. The way your code is structured, `<ul>` elements always follow `<h3>` elements. So, I suggest using jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), like so:

```
jQuery(this).next();
```

That will select the next element after the "hovered" `<h3>`, which will be its `<ul>`. You can then slide that element up or down.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.sidemenugroup h3").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next().slideDown()
  }, function() {
    jQuery(this).next().slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
div.sidemenugroup ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some other text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>2nd List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Refinement

You can simplify your code a bit by making use of jQuery's [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/). Note that [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) will also accept a single function. So, you can trigger the same slide animation when the mouse enters *or* leaves the element. Use this to toggle the slide state.

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Also, to prevent animations from building up in the queue, I recommend adding a [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) before the slide.

See these refinements demonstrated below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("div.sidemenugroup h3").hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next().stop(true, false).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div.sidemenugroup ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
  <h3>Some other text</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>2nd List Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd say that `.next()` would be enough, for the given markup.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [showdevs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31886544/1763929), but I also have to say that this can be done with pure CSS:

```css
ul{
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

h3:hover + ul{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidemenugroup">
    <h3>Some text</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>List Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="sidemenugroup">
    <h3>Some other text</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>List Item 1</li>
        <li>2nd List Item 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And for your slideUp / slideDown animations, you can always use [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdfd8g3u/)

Answer (score 0):

This uses next but specifies the element to slide

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.sidemenugroup h3").hover(function() {
    $(this).next("div.sidemenugroup ul").slideDown()
  }, function(e) {
    $(this).next("div.sidemenugroup ul").slideUp();
  });
});
```

Working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sk36bru8/

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS selectors to get the direct child lists of the div:

```
jQuery( "div.sidemenugroup > ul" ).slideDown()
```

or use jQuery's `children()` function:

```
jQuery( "div.sidemenugroup" ).children( "ul" ).slideDown()
```